# How to improve web-service api throughput?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, api, web-services, uwsgi

I'm new to creating web service. So I'd like to know what i'm missing out on performance (assuming i'm missing something).

I've build a simple flask app. Nothing fancy, it just reads from the DB and responds with the result.
uWSGI is used for WSGI layer. I've run multiple tests and set process=2 and threads=5 based on performance monitoring.

```
processes = 2
threads = 5
enable-threads = True
```

AWS ALB is used for load balancer. uWSGI and Flask app is dockerized and launched in ECS (3 container [1vCPU]).

The for each DB hit, the flask app takes 1 - 1.5 sec to get the data. There is no other lag on the app side. I know it can be optimised. But assuming that the request processing time takes 1 - 1.5 sec, can the throughput be increased?

The throughput I'm seeing is ~60 request per second. I feel it's too low. Is there any way to increase the throughput with the same infra ?

Am i missing something here or is the throughput reasonable given that the DB hit takes 1.5 sec?

Note : It's synchronous.

Comment: 1.5 s for a db access seems slow. But  you haven't explained much in your question. What db? DynamoDB, RDS, some custom db on an ec2 instance? Have you tested access from localhost or some ec2 instance? It only happens in containers? But generally if db access is issue, one can use caching. For dynamodb there is DAX, for RDS you could use ElastiCache.

Comment: @Marcin: Thanks for the prompt response. Currently the DB hit and processing the data takes around 1 sec. Yeah, there is definite scope for improvement there. But assuming that the optimised processing time is 1 sec, I'd like to know if the request processing parallelism can be improved.
FYI : I've tested it from local as well as EC2 instance residing in the same region.
Sorry for the ambiguity in the question. I'll update it.